# Return a component when client does not fetches the data from API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch

I want to return selectively a component when API fails to fetch data if the client enters the username that does `not` exist.

I am fetching the data from API as follows:

```
    async function lichessProfile(username) {
        await fetch(`https://lichess.org/api/user/${username}`)
        .then((res)=>res.json())
        .then((json) => setData(json));
    }
```

And using it as

```
let username =  JSON.stringify(data.username);
```

Now here I am using the function:

```
function showDisplay() {
    if(username === undefined) {
        return(
            <Alert variant={'danger'}>
                <div>
                    <h2>User Does Not Exists !</h2>
                </div>
            </Alert>
        )
    }
    else {
        return(
            <div className="profileContainer">
               
                <Alert variant={'success'}>
                    <div>
                       <h2>User Exists !</h2>
                    </div>
                </Alert>
               
            </div>
        )

    }
}


return(
    <div>
        <div className='searchInput'>
            <input style={{fontFamily:'Unkempt, cursive', padding:'3%',fontSize:'150%',textAlign:'center'}} type="text" onChange={getData} placeholder="search..."/>
        </div>       
        <br/>
        <div className='searchButton'>
            <Button style={{fontSize:'80%',padding:'2%',backgroundColor:'grey'}} className="lichess-button" onClick={()=>lichessProfile(inputData)} >Get Profile</Button>
        </div>
        
        {showDisplay()};  
        {/* Here I am displaying the component */}
        
    </div>
  )
};
```

What I am getting now?
As soon as API does not fetches, I got `unhandled error` like this
"**Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input**". If I use try-catch then nothing happens but only the error got handled.

How to return them selectively?

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: As soon as API does not fetches , I got `unhandled error` like this 
"**Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input**". If I use try-catch then nothing haapens but error got handled only.

Answer (score 0):

`let username =  JSON.stringify(data.username)` doesn't look correct.  You already have:

```
.then((res)=>res.json())
.then((json) => setData(json))
```

So the `data` from `setData` should already be `JSON` because of `res.json()`.

Other than that make sure that you're actually receiving the data you think you should when the username doesn't exist.  I think that if `response.json` tries to convert non JSON data to JSON it will break (in a promise which won't be caught in your custom catch).

Comment: But how we access the username if the below line is wring:
let username =  JSON.stringify(data.username)

Comment: You've set the username using ````setData(json)````, so you can directly use it with ````data.username````.

Answer (score 0):

at some point i dont get what you wanted to do, but here's my code might be a little help for you to get some ideas on what you're trying to achieve for.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n17gux?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Here you are taking values form a defined DB named 'user',  but I do not have a model name. Check The API response here, 
https://lichess.org/api/user/mohit_maroliya

Answer (score -1):

```
let showDisplay;
if(username === undefined) {
    showDisplay = (
        <Alert variant={'danger'}>
            <></>
        </Alert>
    )
} else {
    showDisplay = (
        <div className="profileContainer">
            <Alert variant={'success'}>
                <></>
            </Alert>
        </div>
    )
} 
return(
<div>
    <div className='searchInput'>
        <input style={{fontFamily:'Unkempt, cursive', padding:'3%',fontSize:'150%',textAlign:'center'}} type="text" onChange={getData} placeholder="search..."/>
    </div>       
    <br/>
    <div className='searchButton'>
        <Button style={{fontSize:'80%',padding:'2%',backgroundColor:'grey'}} className="lichess-button" onClick={()=>lichessProfile(inputData)} >Get Profile</Button>
    </div>
    
    {showDisplay};  
    {/* Here I am displaying the component */}
    
</div>)};
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer. There is no explanation on what approach you went by and why.

Comment: But As soon as API does not fetch, I got an unhandled error like this "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input".